# My A* path finding algorithm is not returning the correct path

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

I'm trying to implement an A* pathfinding algorithm and having some trouble with it. According to the various pseudocode examples I've found on the internet, I see no reason as to why it isn't working. The current output seems more akin to a breadth-first search algorithm. I noticed this after attempting to draw out my results. If anyone can spot what exactly I've left out or am doing wrong, I would be extremely grateful. The relevant code is below:

```
public void Astar()
{

    //priority queues automatically sorted (by f)
    Node current = openNodes.peek(); //retrieves node with lowest f

    //System.out.println("(" + current.x + ", " + current.y + ")");
    //System.out.println(current.f);

    //for drawing path (testing)
    currents.add(current);

    //if goal is reached
    if (current.x == goal.x && current.y == goal.y) {
        System.out.println("finished");

    }
    else {

        openNodes.remove(current);
        closedNodes.add(current);

        // neighbor checks
        for (int x = current.x - 1; x <= current.x + 1; x++) {
            for (int y = current.y - 1; y <= current.y + 1; y++) {
                if (x != current.x || y != current.y) {

                    if ((x == current.x - 1 && y == current.y + 1) ||
                            (x == current.x + 1 && y == current.y + 1) ||
                            (x == current.x - 1 && y == current.y - 1) ||
                            (x == current.x + 1 && y == current.y - 1))
                    {

                        Node DiagonalNeighbor = new Node(x, y, current.g + diag, goal); //diagonal node

                        if (!(closedNodes.contains(DiagonalNeighbor)) && !(openNodes.contains(DiagonalNeighbor)) && map[x][y] == 0) {
                            openNodes.add(DiagonalNeighbor);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Node Neighbor = new Node(x, y, current.g + 20, goal);

                        if (!(closedNodes.contains(Neighbor)) && !(openNodes.contains(Neighbor)) && map[x][y] == 0) {
                            openNodes.add(Neighbor);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My Node class:

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{

int x;
int y;

int g;
float h;
float f;

public Node(int x, int y, int g, Node goal){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.g = g;
    this.h = heuristic(goal);
    f = this.g+h;
    //f = h;
}

public Node(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Overrides standard equals method (used to check if a list contains a specific node)
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {

    if(this == other) {
        return true;
    }

    if(other == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if(getClass() != other.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Node test = (Node)other;
    if(this.x == test.x && this.y == test.y) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


//used to sort lists (and sorts priority queue by f) -> [//Collections.sort(openNodes);] - sorts Array List by f values]
@Override
public int compareTo(Node n) {
    return (int) (f - n.f);
}


public float heuristic(Node endNode) {


    //Euclidean distance
    /*
    float y = Math.abs (this.y - endNode.y); //y distance
    float x = Math.abs (this.x - endNode.x); //x distance
    float result = (float)Math.sqrt((y)*(y) +(x)*(x));
    return result;
    */


    //delta max
    float x = Math.abs (this.x - endNode.x); //x distance
    float y = Math.abs (this.y - endNode.y); //y distance
    float result = Math.max(x,y);
    return result;

}

}
```

Another few things worth it to note is that The the goal node is, as its name suggests the target, the starting node is added into the openNode priority queue already and the Astar method will continuously be called in a render method which runs indefinitely (my final objective is to use this in a game). closedNodes and currents are ArrayLists with the latter storing the path that is drawn and that the object should traverse (I talked about this at the top). I hope I've provided enough information. Please don't hesitate to ask me for more.

The grid used is 22x15. if grid[x][y] = 1 then it is an obstacle, it it equals 0 then it is traversable. the starting node is situated at (20,13) and the goal node is at (1,1,). Here is the grid being used. Note that bottom left is (0,0) and top right is (22,15). I know its weird just roll with it.

```
int[][] map = {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, //22


};
```

When I print out the current node path I get the following:

```
(20, 13)
(19, 13)
(20, 12)
(19, 12)
(18, 13)
(20, 11)
(18, 12)
(19, 11)
(18, 11)
(17, 13)
(20, 10)
(17, 12)
(19, 10)
(17, 11)
(18, 10)
(16, 13)
(20, 9)
(17, 10)
(16, 12)
(19, 9)
(16, 11)
(15, 13)
(16, 10)
(17, 9)
(15, 12)
(16, 9)
(15, 11)
(14, 13)
(15, 10)
(17, 8)
(14, 12)
(15, 9)
(16, 8)
(14, 11)
(13, 13)
(15, 8)
(14, 10)
(13, 12)
(17, 7)
(14, 9)
(16, 7)
(13, 11)
(12, 13)
(14, 8)
(15, 7)
(13, 10)
(12, 12)
(17, 6)
(14, 7)
(13, 9)
(16, 6)
(12, 11)
(11, 13)
(13, 8)
(15, 6)
(12, 10)
(11, 12)
(13, 7)
(17, 5)
(14, 6)
(12, 9)
(11, 11)
(16, 5)
(13, 6)
(18, 5)
(12, 8)
(10, 13)
(11, 10)
(15, 5)
(10, 12)
(12, 7)
(17, 4)
(14, 5)
(11, 9)
(10, 11)
(12, 6)
(16, 4)
(13, 5)
(18, 4)
(19, 5)
(11, 8)
(9, 13)
(10, 10)
(15, 4)
(12, 5)
(11, 7)
(19, 4)
(19, 6)
(9, 12)
(17, 3)
(14, 4)
(10, 9)
(9, 11)
(11, 6)
(16, 3)
(13, 4)
(18, 3)
(10, 8)
(20, 5)
(8, 13)
(9, 10)
(11, 5)
(15, 3)
(10, 7)
(19, 3)
(19, 7)
(20, 6)
(8, 12)
(20, 4)
(17, 2)
(9, 9)
(14, 3)
(10, 6)
(8, 11)
(20, 7)
(16, 2)
(20, 3)
(13, 3)
(9, 8)
(18, 2)
(7, 13)
(10, 5)
(8, 10)
(9, 7)
(19, 2)
(7, 12)
(17, 1)
(8, 9)
(14, 2)
(9, 6)
(16, 1)
(8, 8)
(20, 2)
(13, 2)
(18, 1)
(6, 13)
(9, 5)
(7, 10)
(15, 1)
(8, 7)
(19, 1)
(6, 12)
(7, 9)
(14, 1)
(7, 8)
(20, 1)
(13, 1)
(5, 13)
(6, 10)
(7, 7)
(5, 12)
(6, 9)
(7, 6)
(6, 8)
(4, 13)
(6, 7)
(4, 12)
(6, 6)
(7, 5)
(4, 11)
(5, 8)
(6, 5)
(5, 7)
(5, 6)
(7, 4)
(4, 10)
(4, 8)
(5, 5)
(6, 4)
(4, 7)
(5, 4)
(4, 6)
(7, 3)
(3, 8)
(4, 5)
(6, 3)
(8, 3)
(3, 7)
(4, 4)
(5, 3)
(3, 6)
(7, 2)
(4, 3)
(2, 8)
(3, 5)
(6, 2)
(8, 2)
(9, 3)
(2, 7)
(3, 4)
(2, 9)
(5, 2)
(9, 2)
(2, 6)
(7, 1)
(4, 2)
(1, 8)
(2, 5)
(6, 1)
(3, 2)
(8, 1)
(10, 3)
(1, 7)
(2, 4)
(1, 9)
(5, 1)
(2, 10)
(9, 1)
(1, 6)
(10, 2)
(2, 3)
(4, 1)
(1, 10)
(1, 5)
(10, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 1)
(11, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 1)
(2, 11)
(11, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 11)
(1, 2)
(11, 1)
(1, 1)
finished
```

I wish I could show you how it looks when it draws it but I would have to be able to send a video to do that.

Comment: Can you add the input you are giving this program, the result you expect and the result you are getting?

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific problem** or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok jrook will do. The desired behaviour is that of the A* algorithm i don't see the problem there.

Comment: The FAQ talks about a specific problem. A MCVE is always helpful. You could, for example, construct a sample input with an expected and an observed output to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I don't see where you are saving the back-pointers for each path state. Just keeping one list for the path like `currents.add(current);` isn't going to work. You need, for each node, to save a pointer to the previous node. Then write a function that walks the pointers backward from the goal node to the start node.

Comment: Ok let me write up an example output quick

Comment: MFisher KDX. Wouldn't the previous pointer node not just be the previous current node added to the list. seeing as though each successive current node is a neighbour to the last current node.

Comment: Also Turing85. It will take too long to write up a proper example now and its quite late where I am. but just look up A* pathfinding, it will tell you how it is supposed to behave.

Comment: No. Because your search branches. For each node you evaluate, you push up to 8 neighbors on your priority queue. The 8th neighbor you push has a previous pointer to the current node being evaluated, not to the node immediately in front of it on the priority queue.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. How would I go about implementing this change?

Comment: Do you have an algorithm textbook that explains Best First Search? A* is just a special case. Otherwise, see the Wikipedia page on A*. There is pseudocode there you can follow that shows how/when to update the back-pointers.

Comment: Ok thanks, MFisherKDX will give it a look.